# Deeplinking into a telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

I have a simple use case. When a user clicks the link below,

> T.me/MycompanynameBot?start=Microsoft

I want to show him 3 inline buttons corresponding to 3 Telegram channels within Microsoft. Is this possible?

The key is the bot must be able to retrieve the parameters from the URL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible to retrieve bot parameter via [answerCallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery)

> Alternatively, the user can be redirected to the specified Game URL. For this option to work, you must first create a game for your bot via **`@Botfather`** and accept the terms. Otherwise, you may use links like:
>   **t.me/your_bot?start=XXXX** 
>   that open your bot with a parameter.

Here is an example I made for you :

```
 {
   "ok": true,
   "result": [{
     "update_id": 89590932,
     "message": {
       "message_id": 5978,
       "from": {
         "id": 223110107,
         "is_bot": false,
         "first_name": "Ğąme",
         "last_name": "Ǿver!",
         "username": "GameO7er",
         "language_code": "en"
       },
       "chat": {
         "id": 223110107,
         "first_name": "Ğąme",
         "last_name": "Ǿver!",
         "username": "GameO7er",
         "type": "private"
       },
       "date": 1579094448,
       "text": "/start Microsoft",
       "entities": [{
         "offset": 0,
         "length": 6,
         "type": "bot_command"
       }]
     }
   }]
 }
```

As you can see **type=bot_command** so you can parse the message `if (type == "bot_command")` and get text and substring `/start` from the original text or what ever you want to do.

In many cases I detect users with the parameters for example when I wanna to know who invited this user to bot I share the link in this format:

> t.me/NameBot?start=**ReferUserID**

for example :

> t.me/NameBot?start=**223110107**

is my ID and I can see how many user I've invited to the bot.

Hope be useful.